# extract substring using regex in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, regex-group

If I have the following pattern in some text:

```
def articleContent =  "<![CDATA[ Hellow World ]]>"
```

I would like to extract the "Hellow World" part, so I use the following code to match it:

```
def contentRegex = "<![CDATA[ /(.)*/ ]]>"
def contentMatcher = ( articleContent =~ contentRegex )
println contentMatcher[0]
```

However I keep getting a null pointer exception because the regex doesn't seem to be working, what would be the correct regex for "any peace of text", and how to collect it from a string?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try:

```
def result = (articleContent =~ /<!\[CDATA\[(.+)]]>/)[ 0 ]​[ 1 ]
```

However I worry that you are planning to parse xml with regular expressions. If this cdata is part of a larger valid xml document, better to use an xml parser

Comment: Its not for valid xml... that's the problem. THank you very much!

Comment: I'm new to Groovy. Can you please explain why we need to dereference the matcher with `[0]` in order to get a list of groups?

Comment: @Gili Because there can be multiple matches, int this case  `"<![CDATA[ Hellow World ]]> <![CDATA[ Hi Everyone ]]>"` you could extract `Hi Everyone` with `[1][1]`.

Answer (score 10):

The code below shows the substring extraction using regex in groovy:

```
class StringHelper {
@NonCPS
static String stripSshPrefix(String gitUrl){
    def match = (gitUrl =~ /ssh:\/\/(.+)/)
    if (match.find()) {
        return match.group(1)
    }
    return gitUrl
  }
static void main(String... args) {
    def gitUrl = "ssh://git@github.com:jiahut/boot.git"
    def gitUrl2 = "git@github.com:jiahut/boot.git"
    println(stripSshPrefix(gitUrl))
    println(stripSshPrefix(gitUrl2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late to the party but try using backslash when defining your pattern, example:

```
 def articleContent =  "real groovy"
 def matches = (articleContent =~ /gr\w{4}/) //grabs 'gr' and its following 4 chars
 def firstmatch = matches[0]  //firstmatch would be 'groovy'
```

you were on the right track, it was just the pattern definition that needed to be altered.

References:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html

Answer (score 1):

One more sinle-line solution additional to tim_yates's one

```
def result = articleContent.replaceAll(/<!\[CDATA\[(.+)]]>/,/$1/)
```

Please, take into account that in case of regexp doesn't match then result will be equal to the source. Unlikely in case of

```
def result = (articleContent =~ /<!\[CDATA\[(.+)]]>/)[0]​[1]
```

it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the actual string was multi-line like below

```
ID : AB-223
Product : Standard Profile
Start Date : 2020-11-19 00:00:00
Subscription : Annual
Volume : 11
Page URL : null
Commitment : 1200.00
Start Date : 2020-11-25 00:00:00
```

I wanted to extract the `Start Date` value from this string so here is how my script looks like

```
def matches = (originalData =~ /(?<=Actual Start Date :).*/)
def extractedData = matches[0]
```

This regex extracts the string content from each line which has a prefix matching `Start Date :`

In my case, the result is is `2020-11-25 00:00:00`

**Note :** If your `originalData` is a multi-line string then in groovy you can include it as follows

```
def originalData = 
"""
ID : AB-223
Product : Standard Profile
Start Date : 2020-11-19 00:00:00
Subscription : Annual
Volume : 11
Page URL : null
Commitment : 1200.00
Start Date : 2020-11-25 00:00:00
"""
```

---

This script looks simple but took me some good time to figure out few things so I'm posting this here.