# Groovy - Substring from a string

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
def testString = '''
relkey = CAT_RELEASE_AUG_2018
relkey2 = CAT_RELEASE_SEP_2019
'''
```

using groovy - how can i get both the relkey and relkey2 values - Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract substring using regex in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536921/extract-substring-using-regex-in-groovy)

Comment: Can I have the example please as I have multiple releases keys - thanks

Comment: You should not to store it like this, that's the first point I want to mention, better will be use eg. `Map` for key-value pairs, or, at least you should to use eg. String array.. 
Then you will be able to iterate over each element of the object make split or substring of these specific strings

Comment: can i have the example please. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
String val = testString.substring(testString.indexOf("=")+1)
```

For more options, you can use this too.

**Method 2:**

```
String val = testString.split("=")[1]
```

But it is up to you.

For example to load as map: 
There are many methods to load as map but for simple example,

```
String a= "h=1"
Map kv=[:]
List b = a.split("="); 
kv[b[0]]=b[1] 
println kv
```

Comment: need to get the two key values. Can i have the example for this please

Comment: @garlapak There are many methods to do that. I have updated the answer with a simple example to do that. Enjoy learning ...

Comment: @garlapak If you want to explore more, My [Learn_Groovy](https://github.com/Bhanuchander210/Learn_Groovy/tree/master/Chapter_1%20-%20Basic_Initiatives/4.Map) repo may help you . . .